# What does Hinduism say about intelligent life on other planets?

Tags: vivekananda, universe

Swami Vivekanada once wrote in a poem:

> Lo! The sun, the moon, The moving planets and the shining stars,
> Spheres of abode by myriads in the skies...

This is only a vague hint. Is there anything more specific about extraterrestrial life in Hinduism? The more specific the better.

Answer (score 1):

OK. Let's see. You are talking, I believe, about extraterrestrials with biological body (Bhootha or Pinda). We don't want to get into the ones without a body - in spirit form. Neither are you talking about the in-dwelling Bhootatma - consciousness - which exists in Brahmandam(universe) and hence extra-terrestrial and Pindandam(inside the body). You also are not talking about the ones that exist in the mid-regions, lower regions, with lesser planes of existence, say the ones with 4-legs, Predha, Pischacha etc. All the above are referred to in Vedas. Besides that, there are pot-born sons, Mind-born sons( of Brahma) And twice-born sons..There are sages running stars, Dhruva, Atri etc. They are extra terrestrial. They are also referred to in the Vedas. All of them alive!! So, we have to be very very specific :-). Considering the fact that you might be referring to the extra-terrestrial beings kindda similar to us. To answer your more general 'extra-terrestrial' question & assuming specific references to human-like beings.

Yes.

Gandharvas are extraterrestrial & are music/art aficionados.
Rig Veda 9.113.3,  Rig Veda 10.10.4 are about their actions. Refer to the Wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandharva